# flutter audio_service not working, errors in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: flutter

I am attempting to recreate the audio_service tutorial on GitHub and it is not working, no sound is playing when you click the play button.  I have observed an error in the AndroidManifest.xml which seems to be related - the documentation of course requires you add lines to the AndriodManifest.xml file.

However I am getting errors on the lines  and  which I suspect could be causing the problem.  The errors are "Class referenced in the manifest, _______ , was not found in the project or the libraries / Unresolved package '___' " for both.

I did include these dependencies in my pubspec.yaml:
audio_service: ^0.15.1
just_audio: ^0.5.2

Note that I am having the same problem on both my Windows 10 development environment and on my MacBookPro running Catalina.  Does anyone know how I can resolve this?  What am I missing?

Here is my complete AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tv.realhelp.new_audio_service_test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="new_audio_service_test"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <service android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: have you run 'flutter pub get' after added library to yaml file?

Comment: Yes, of course.